# Azure web app hosted WCF services return 404

Tags: wcf, azure-web-app-service

Trying to move a legacy web application from IIS8 to an Azure web app. The app includes many ajax calls to WCF services that are built with no endpoint configuration, similar to the method described here: http://stevemichelotti.com/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config/

As suggested in the article, System.Web.Routing is used to route requests to the correct service. For example, my global.asax includes routes like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("svc/cmp/",  new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CompanyService)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("svc/cont/", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ContactsService)));
```

So, a request for http://example.com/svc/cmp/GetCompany?id=1234 would be routed to CompanyService for handling.

These calls all work fine when running on IIS, but return 404 not found errors on Azure web app.

I tried adding handlers to web.config, like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

Also tried adding a handler mapping in the Azure app settings to have all extensions (*) handled by %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll.

No luck in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by deleting the Azure web app and recreating it. It was originally created with the WordPress template with a virtual directory/application hosting the .net portion of the site.

Apparently, not all routing modules are loaded with the WordPress template so the WCF services were not routed correctly. After it was recreated with the web app template all the services worked just fine.

**Update**

This issue resurfaced after re-installing WordPress. Now that I have a better understanding of what's going on I thought I should update in case anyone has a similar issue.

WordPress is installed in web site root and the WCF services are in a child app. Turns out that WordPress created a rewrite rule in the web.config of the root which broke my WCF services. The rewrite rule looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Wordpress: https://example.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This rule has to do with enabling pretty permalinks and says "if the URL does not correspond to a file or a folder on the file system, it will rewrite the URL to the index.php file".

Well, my WCF services have URLs that don't correspond to a file or folder, so they were all broken. The situation was resolved by clearing rewrite rules in the web.config in the child app:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Lesson learned.